# How to add inline code to #| fig-cap: in quarto

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

**Update:**

@harre. I encountered an issue.

It works perfect with `mtcars` dataset.

But when I try to use a loaded dataframe it says:

```
Fehler in nrow(df_xxx) : Objekt 'df_xxx' nicht gefunden
Ruft auf: paste -> nrow
Fehler in yaml::yaml.load(meta, eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Could not evaluate expression: paste(nrow(df_xxx), "blabla")
Ruft auf: .main ... FUN -> parse_block -> partition_chunk -> <Anonymous>
Ausf�hrung angehalten
```

It seems that quarto looks first `#|...` in this case `df_xxx` is not generated. Although it is in the environment we have no access to it.
Any idea?

**Original question:**
This is a working quarto exmple:

````
---
title: "test"
format: revealjs
---

## Quarto example


```{r}
#| label: fig-plot_mtcars
#| fig-cap: nrow(mtcars).

plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$disp)
```
````

**output:**

[image]

**How can I add a inline code to `fig.cap:`:**
**desired output:**
[image]

I have tried with `#| fig-cap: paste("bla", nrow(mtcars))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to tell the quarto YAML that you're parsing an R expression to be evaluated. I.e.:

```r
#| fig-cap: !expr nrow(mtcars)
```

For reference, see:

https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html#chunk-options

Comment: Have you loaded the dataset df_xxx within a block in the quarto document? Markdown documents won't load from your environment.

Comment: can you explain more about your comment?  Can you point me to a reference or describe in more detail how one would go about implementing your suggestion? Thanks!